# Ambiguity about proving that the square root of 2 is irrational

Tags: roots, radicals

To prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational; first, we say that $\sqrt{2}$ is either rational or irrational. Then, by assuming that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, we reach a logical contradiction that shows that our assumption is false. So $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

But my problem is with the first part where we said that $\sqrt{2}$ is either rational or irrational. How do we know that $\sqrt{2}$ is either rational or irrational? For example, **how do we know and prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is not undefined?**  How can we prove that it is either rational or irrational and is not out of these two states?

Comment: "how do we know and prove that $\sqrt2$
 is not undefined?" We first define it. Or if we are lazy, we only prove that no rational is a square root of $2.$

Comment: With a little calculus , we can easily show that $f(x)=x^2-2$ has a unique positive real root which has the property that its square is $2$ , this root must therefore be $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Expanding a little on Peter's comment, If a number is not in the domain of a function, the function itself is said to be "undefined" for that number. Peter has shown $\sqrt{2}$ is in the domain, hence it is, in a real sense, defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we prove that it is either rational or irrational and is not out of these two states?

By definition, a rational number is a number that can be written as the quotient $\dfrac{p}{q}$ of two integers $p$ and $q \neq 0$. Any number that does not satisfy this is called an irrational number. So every number falls within one of these two categories. For $\sqrt{2}$, you are asked to prove that is irrational, and you prove that by contradiction. You assume the opposite, i.e. $\sqrt{2}$ is not irrational, that leaves only one option for it which is to be rational. From here, you proceed to find a contradiction.

Comment: So with your explanation, $\Large\frac{5}{0}$ is an irrational number and it is defined.

Comment: You are calling it a "number" and then expressing it in an undefined way, which does not make it a number, to begin with. I said, "every number falls within one of these categories". So I was referring to defined quantities. To project this on your question, can you find $\alpha$ such that $\sqrt{2} = \dfrac{\alpha}{0}$? Also, read the comments under your post, they provided rigorous ways to define $\sqrt{2}$.